# Can we really track IP address of User in Django for blocking manually

Tags: python, django, ip, django-views

I am building a django app where users submit data which is displayed on home page.

As there is not going to be huge traffic, I personally want to block data based upon the IP address!

Now, I need to know the IP address of the user! How do I get it?
I searched a lot on web and specifically on this site, but didn't get a simple and proper answer that does the job.

can anyone tell me how to do it?

Is there any API stuff present that helps me block specific users (may be locations/ continents - I guess GeoDjango is there for it).

Comment: keep in mind people can use proxies or vpn to change their IP ....

Comment: What's the solution for this? Any neat/ simple/ reliable would be appreciated

Comment: +1 to @JoranBeasley. For that matter many people can just disconnect and reconnect their DSL modem, or walk 40 feet to the next corner with their iPhone. There's also the fact that many people are sharing IPs—you ban one guy, and you've randomly banned 300 different central-Boston-area AT&T customers over the course of the next week.

Comment: And there is no simple, reliable solution. If you want people to be anonymous, you can't block individuals (at least not without the kind of massive human effort that Wikipedia and a few other communities put into it).

Comment: you guys are right! my requirement is quite simple. Say 100 hits per day is too big in my case (FOR NOW).

Comment: You just want to prevent any single IP from making more than 100 hits per day? Keep in mind that 50 people behind the same corporate filewall each hitting your site twice will show up as the same IP hitting you 100 times. But if you still want that, yes, that is doable (although possibly better to do on a router/F5/etc. than in the server itself).